# How to write a custom function with a completion handler?

Tags: swift

I'm not quite clear about the syntax concerning the creation of a custom function with completion handler and its usage.

Below is a function I have written to draw a UIBezier path.  I want this function to return a UIbezierpath to be fed to a completion handler. Have i written this correctly? I want the completion handler to not return anything.

Based on my code below is my 'returnedPath' the RETURNED UIbezierpath that i can subsequently use?

implementation of custom function:

```
outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath(topLeft: tl, topRight: tr, bottomRight: br, bottomLeft: bl) { (returnedPath) in

}


func outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath(topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint, bottomLeft: CGPoint, completion: (UIBezierPath) -> ()) -> UIBezierPath{

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: topLeft)
    path.addLine(to: topRight)
    path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
    path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
    path.addLine(to: topLeft)
    path.close()

    return path
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for your `outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath` function to have a `completion` parameter. There's nothing asynchronous about your `outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath` function. It simply creates a bezier path and returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use a completion when the task inside the function is asynchronous and hence code in `outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath` isn't then no need for a completion , should be

```
let path = outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath(topLeft: tl, topRight: tr, bottomRight: br, bottomLeft: bl)
```

---

```
func outlineImageBorderWithBezierPath(topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint, bottomLeft: CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath { 
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: topLeft)
    path.addLine(to: topRight)
    path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
    path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
    path.addLine(to: topLeft)
    path.close() 
    return path
}
```